# Accessing a double from one method to another one

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am a big beginner in java and just need to know how to use this variable from one method to another as it is part of an assignment. please help.

```
public class parking {
 public static void input(String args[]) {

    int hoursParked = IO.getInt("(\\(\\ \n(-,-)      How many hours were you parked?\no_(\")(\")");
    double bill = hoursParked * 0.5 + 2;
}

 public static void output(String args[]) {
     System.out.println("         Parking");
     System.out.println("$2 Fee plus $0.50 every hour!");
     System.out.println("\nYour amount owed is $" + bill + "0");

 }
```

}

Comment: I declared bill in method input and need to put it in output method in a SOUT.

Comment: You need to understand scope of the variables. https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html

Comment: those are just local variables inside your `input` method. They're not class variables. they need to be declared as such if you want to use them across methods.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `bill` is a *local variable* in `input`. You cannot refer to that variable from outside `input`.

If `input` and `output` are to be separate methods, then the usual thing would be to make them *instance* methods and to create a `parking` instance to use the methods. That lets you store `bill` as an *instance variable* (aka "instance field"). (Normally classes are initially capped, e.g. `Parking`, so I'll do that here.)

```
public class Parking {
    private double bill;

    public Parking() {
        this.bill = 0.0;
    }

    public void input() {
        int hoursParked = IO.getInt("(\\(\\ \n(-,-)      How many hours were you parked?\no_(\")(\")");
        this.bill = hoursParked * 0.5 + 2; // Or perhaps `+=`
    }

    public void output() {
        System.out.println("         Parking");
        System.out.println("$2 Fee plus $0.50 every hour!");
        System.out.println("\nYour amount owed is $" + this.bill + "0");
    }
}
```

(Java makes using the `this.` when referring to instance members optional. I always advocate using it, as above, to make it clear we're not using a local variable. Other opinions vary, saying it's unnecessary and verbose. It's a matter of style.)

Usage

```
Parking p = new Parking();
p.input(args);
p.output();
```

Alternately, *return* the value of `bill` from `input` and then pass it into `output`:

```
public class Parking {

    public static double input() {
        int hoursParked = IO.getInt("(\\(\\ \n(-,-)      How many hours were you parked?\no_(\")(\")");
        return hoursParked * 0.5 + 2;
    }

    public static void output(double bill) {
        System.out.println("         Parking");
        System.out.println("$2 Fee plus $0.50 every hour!");
        System.out.println("\nYour amount owed is $" + bill + "0");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
double bill = parking.input(args);
parking.output(bill);
```

---

Side note: Since neither `input` nor `output` did anything with `args`, I've removed it above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare as class variables, then access it.

```
public class parking {

private double bill;

public void input(String args[]) {
int hoursParked = IO.getInt("(\\(\\ \n(-,-)      How many hours were you parked?\no_(\")(\")");
bill = hoursParked * 0.5 + 2;
}

public void output(String args[]) {
 System.out.println("         Parking");
 System.out.println("$2 Fee plus $0.50 every hour!");
 System.out.println("\nYour amount owed is $" + bill + "0");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!